# Variável na main() é global?

Tags: c, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Li que variáveis globais são aquelas que declaramos fora de todas as funções utilizando `#define` e dessa forma elas poderiam ser utilizadas por todas as funções de um programa. Entretanto, me foi informado que as variáveis declaradas na `main()` são globais. Tenho quase certeza que isso é falso, visto que as variáveis que declaramos no main só podem ser utilizadas por outras funções se passarmos ela por parâmetro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não, `main()` é uma função como outra qualquer. As variáveis declaradas dentro dela só são vistas dentro dela. O máximo que pode-se fazer é acessar indiretamente os endereços onde estas variáveis foram alocadas. Como tudo o que foi declarado na `main()` existirá por toda vida da aplicação, isto é possível. Mas é algo anormal e como disse antes, o acesso ao conteúdo é indireto e não pelas variáveis em si que não podem ser vistas.

As variáveis globais são realmente declaradas fora de funções, mas os `#define` sequer são variáveis. São apenas textos que são substituídos antes da compilação, nada mais que isto, desaparece completamente do código.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Main é a função principal do programa. E variáveis declaradas fora de qualquer função(escopo) são globais. A que estão dentro das funções são locais.
 As globais podem ser usadas no programa inteiro e as locais apenas no escopo.

Answer (score 0):

Quanto a declaração variáveis fixas e constantes:

COMANDO:

**#define:** Cria um rótulo para um valor qualquer e não ocupa espaço em memória.

**const:** Simula uma constante na memória, ou seja, cria uma variável com valor fixo, assim o compilador aloca um espaço em memória para a varável.

Comment: Não foi isso que foi perguntado mas o maior problema da resposta é que um valor criado com `#define` ocupa lugar na memória, como qualquer dado. Outro problema é chamar constante de variável.

Comment: Eu olhei no livro do Mazano, na verdade o compilador entende assim. Vou dar outra olhada, mas foi assim que aprendi.

Comment: Pode citar o trecho que diz isso? Coloque contexto. Ou você entendeu errado ou o livro é ruim.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha entendido errado, mas o Manzano não é ruim não, se ele fosse ruim não kkk tenho aula com ele até! "Uma constante em linguagem C pode ser simulada por meio do uso do comando const, que cria na memória uma variável e estabelece um valor fixo (imutável) ue não poderá ser modificado até o termino da execução do programa."

Comment: Acabei de arrumar ali em cima, mas o livro estava certo, acabei invertendo o #define e o const.

Comment: Mas a resposta continua errada e ainda não responde ao que foi perguntado. **Se** o livro diz isto, eu afirmo que ele é ruim.

Comment: Não sei, eu não tenho aula com ele, não li o livro dele, não vi o trecho citado. Então não posso falar. Mas se eu tivesse essas informações eu poderia avaliar já que tenho experiência para isto. Quem tem conhecimento inicial apenas, não consegue avaliar o que é bom ou não, para essa pessoa a fonte inicial que ela teve é sempre boa. Pode ser a melhor coisa que você poderia ter acesso ou pode ser algo que está te ensinando tudo errado.